# custom radio buttons in listview

Tags: android

I've made my normal radio buttons custom by adding custom drawables and setting them in an xml file, but I can't seem to achieve the same thing with the radio buttons generated by choice_mode_single in a listview. I've looked around in the source code, but couldn't figure out why they are still default, can somebody please help me?:P

Answer (score 0):

you can set selector for radio button

as follow

http://blog.devminded.com/posts/custom-android-radiobutton

just you need image accordingly your design.

Comment: you have write custom adapter that contains radio button

Comment: ehh.. thought so, was hoping for this to work somehow.. kinda dumb they don't change by default.. ty sir